# Creating a list of CheckBoxes 

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

Okay so basically I am new to C# and I am currently working for a company that develops ecommerce software and I am having an issue that I can't seem to crack.

I  have two columns and I want to add a third column that displays a list of check boxes but I only want to display these checkboxes when the other two(or one) of the fields displays some form of data in it, I.E:

```
            Name Type Check
            lol   lol
```

I also want these check boxes to be automatically ticked.

Another issue is that I also want to make it so when checked the products are displayed in our search, but if they are unticked I wish them to be hidden but not deleted.

I am currently using GridView as I don't want to have to rewrite the rest of what is already there as it communicates with a SQL database which I know nothing about yet.

We are not using ASP, we are using XAML & C# (both of which I have very little knowledge in.) The below image is a bad drawing of what it needs to look like.

[image]

Comment: What approach are you using for setting values in your app... are you using DataBinding?  Setting values directly?  Also, you say XAML, but what type:  Silverlight, WIndows 8, WPF?

Comment: I am using WPF and as for how we are setting the values, I believe we are using Databinding, I'm not hugely familiar with a lot of the C# language at the minute hence why I am struggling a bit, the job was based off a, learn as I go basis. ^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad, and somewhat difficult to answer.  In short, what you want to look at is the `Visibility` property on the controls.

By setting `Visibility` to `Collapsed`, the UI will not display the element.  You can set `Visibility` based on the value of another XAML element or data delement if you want, but you'll need to implement a class that implements IValueConverter to make the conversion.

One of the most common of the value converters is a "boolean to visibility" converter.  If you search on the Internets, you'll be able to find examples of these.  You can copy that approach and create an "EmptyToVisibilityConverter" or "NullToVisibilityConverter" or whatever else you need.  Once you have that converter, you just specify it in the binding for the visibility.  For example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <conv:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVis"/>
</Page.Resources>

<CheckBox ... Checked={Binding ThisBoxIsChecked} 
              Visibility={Binding SomeOtherValue, 
                          Converter={StaticResource NullToVis}}"/>
```

Keep in mind that your databinding between the content of the control, and the visibility properties need not be the same.  You can bind your content to one value, and visibility to another.

If you're not using databinding, you're going to have to set these in the codebehind.  But why wouldn't you be using databinding?

**EDIT:  Here's a working example.**

*If this isn't what you're looking for, then I'm being obtuse and not understanding the question*

I recommend you start a blank project, throw this into it, and play around with it a bit to get a feel for how to set things up.  XAML has a relatively steep learning curve, and there are usually a couple ways to accomplish what you need, but you really need a foundational understanding of databinding and INotifyPropertyChanged (which I didn't get into in this example).

Here's the C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace CheckboxList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Create a viewmodel and add some data to it.
            var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
            viewModel.Items.Add(new Data() {Name = "lol", Type = "lol", Selected = true});
            viewModel.Items.Add(new Data() { Name = "lol", Type = "not_lol", Selected = true });
            viewModel.Items.Add(new Data() { Name = "not_lol", Type = "not_lol", Selected = true });

            //Set the window's datacontext to the ViewModel.  This will make binding work.
            this.DataContext = viewModel;

        }
    }

    //This is the ViewModel used to bind your data 
    public class MyViewModel 
    {
        //This could just be a List<Data> but ObservableCollection<T> will automatically
        //update your UI when items are added or removed from the collection.
        public ObservableCollection<Data> Items { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        }
    }

    //Just a sample class to hold the data for the grid.
    //This is the class that is contained in the ObservableColleciton in the ViewModel
    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }


    //This is an example converter.  It looks to see if the element is set to "lol" 
    //If so, it returns Visibility.Collapsed.  Otherwise, it returns Visibility.Visible.
    public class LolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value is string)
            {
                var input = (string) value;
                if (string.Equals(input, "lol", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }

            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="CheckboxList.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:CheckboxList="clr-namespace:CheckboxList"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Create an instance of LolToVisibilityConverter and call it "LolToVis" -->
        <CheckboxList:LolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="LolToVis"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">  <!--Bind the contents of the Items collection in our viewmodel -->
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/> <!-- bind this element to this column-->
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/> <!-- bind this element to this column-->
                    <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Selected" >  <!-- because we don't want this to just display true/false, we need to set up a template-->
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!-- we set the Visibility property to Name, and the converter to LolToVis-->
                                <!-- whenever this field will be displayed, it calls the converter to convert the string to a Visibility value-->
                                <!-- The visibility value is checked to determine whether or not the element should be displayed-->
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Visibility="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource LolToVis}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I was not clear enough in my OP, sorry about that.

Comment: Woops, cut out before I finished.
The software relays to the clients website and I want to hide the data (the product that they wish to hide/show) on the website, not our own personal UI, the part I am currently looking at is a section that allows them to setup special offer groups IE, all chocolate bars are reduced rates and be able to pick which chocolate bars to show and be able to kepe that cat for future reference, but at the minute the major issue is the checkboxes as once I have got them done I can show my boss some form of progress :p

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used in the past to create a checkbox for each datagridview row... I then use the datagridview_cellcontentclick event handler to change the value of the checkbox when clicked.  In the context of the code below, I have a custom class that consisted a program name, a window title, and an open file or url. I then created a global list "oplist" that was of the type custom custructor.  I then specified the column Headers when I added the items from the list to the datagridview.  Then adding or removing anything from the datagridview becomes extremely easy.  All you have to do is remove or add the item to the list and then refresh the datagridview.

```
    public void addOpenProgramsToDataGrid()
    {
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        {
            column.HeaderText = "Selected";
            column.Name = "Selected";
            column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
            column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
            column.ThreeState = false;
            column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
            column.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }

        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, column); // This is to be a checkbox column
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "X";


        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Process Name:";

        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Window Title";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Open File or URL";

        dataGridView1.RowCount = opList.Count;
        //opList.RemoveRange(0, opList.Count);
        for (int a = 0; a < opList.Count; a++)
        {
            openProgram tempProgram = new openProgram();
            tempProgram = opList[a];
            dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value = true;

            dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[1].Value = tempProgram.processName;
            dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[2].Value = tempProgram.windowTitle;
            dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[3].Value = tempProgram.openFileOrURL;
        }
        selectAllCheckBox.Checked = true;
    }
```

Comment: This is much easier to handle declaratively with XAML and databinding.